# Azure function DefaultAzureCredential Method not Found Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to read secrets from a Azure Key Vault in my azure function c# script, but I'm facing an error

I already create a function.proj file with content below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.6.0" />       
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

I enabled the **System assigned** from my Function App and it created a Object Id number.
Then copied this number and added it to my Key Vault Access policies at Select principal option and choose Get and List for Secret Permissions

When I try this code below:

```
string keyVaultUri = "https://my-vault-test.vault.azure.net/";
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = client.GetSecret("first-secret");
```

error:

> 2022-05-04T16:41:51.383 [Error] Executed 'Functions.myFff' (Failed,
> Id=number..., Duration=574ms) Method not found: 'Void
> Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext..ctor(System.String[], System.String,
> System.String, System.String)'.

Comment: Seems like a deployment problem.  How are you uploading the package to the Function App?

Comment: I've uploaded it by the Storage Account File Share, inside function folder

Answer (score 0):

I changed the versions of the packages and it worked well...

1.5.0 for Azure.Identity

4.2.0 for Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets